# Unique pairs based on multi values

Tags: arcpy, tabulate, unique-value

I will try to be as detailed as I can with the purpose and walkthrough of the situation.

I have 2 Feature Classes (fc1 and fc2).

**fc1** is a polygon shapefile **with no** overlapping polygons and an id for each polygon on field **code** (Int)

**fc2** is a polygon shapefile **with** overlapping polygons and an id for each polygon on field **pcode** (String)

I want to find for **each** polygon in **fc1** the **pcode** that covers it the most. If more than one pcodes covers it the most, then I pick the **pcode** that is sorted **FIRST**.

In order to find a way through this, I wrote a code with the following steps and it produces the result that I want.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
F = OrderedDict([])
arcpy.Union_analysis([[fc1],[fc2]],'Test1','ALL','','GAPS')
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management('Test1','Test2','"code" <> -1')
arcpy.Dissolve_management('Test2','Test3',['code','pcode'],'','SINGLE_PART','DISSOLVE_LINES')
arcpy.AddField_management('Test3','area','DOUBLE')
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor('Test3',['SHAPE@AREA','area']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[1] = row[0]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
arcpy.Sort_management('Test3','Test4','code ASCENDING;area DESCENDING;pcode ASCENDING')
arcpy.Statistics_analysis('Test4','Test5',[['pcode','FIRST']],'code')
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('Test5',['FIRST_pcode','code']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        F.update({row[1]:row[0]})
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc1,['code','pcode']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[1] = F[row[0]]
```

The previous version of my question was posted because I was looking for a faster way because the above code takes about **6 minutes** to finish.

From my search here and in other websites, I didn't find anything that can alter **Dissolve** with sth else unless someone has sth to suggest (it is the most time consuming process here).

For the rest, I didn't manage to find anything, so I hope you can help me out with this.

Supplemental for @radouxju comment:

I used the Tabulated Intersection tool but for some reason it miscalculates the area and the results are not correct. The polygon with code "4" is completely covered by the polygons with pcode 45194229099040 and 45194229099039 but the tool understands that it is partly covered. See the image below:

[image: Miscalculation of Tabulated Intersection tool]

As you can see there is a difference on the 3rd decimal and because of this the Summary Statistics selects the incorrect **pcode** (in this case 451942290990**40** instead of 451942290990**39**).

Comment: Have you looked at the Summary Statistics tool?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know if am using it correctly. How would you use it?

Comment: Without seeing some sample records as part of your question it is not possible to advise. I recommend experimenting with your data to see what different summary and case fields can do for you.

Comment: The case field must be one the code and nothing else. When I put anything else it produces a table with more records than the wanted one. The statistics fields are the other two. I put them one by one, together, I changed the order of them with no luck.

Comment: I made a zip file with the sample you asked and the result that I want. [Sample](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=AF5E4C8DEC50543E!471926&authkey=!ANvAgDFRJulQJ6Q&ithint=file%2czip). I hope that will help!

Comment: By sample I meant just a picture of a few rows and columns of your input and expected output.

Comment: thiqs become similar to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110459/calculate-the-majority-of-one-polygon-in-another-fishnet . Do you have an advanced licence (for the tabulate intersection tool)?

Comment: I will check it and let you know. I didn't know the existence of this tool.

Comment: As you can see above, besides the license level that is not so important, the miscalculation of area produces different results.

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is a simple way to achieve this :

Create a new fild to concatenate code and pcode ( str(!code!) + "_" + !pcode!)

Use summary statistics to get the maximum area value for each unique code_pcode

Join this value to the initial table (based on code field)

if necessary, select the rows where `area = max_area`

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work either. Any other ideas?

Comment: this should definitely work, or I don't understand what you want to achieve. What step is not working ?

Comment: All steps are working but the final result is not the wanted one.

Comment: It would be easier to understand with an example. In my case with A A 300, A B 400, A B 500 you find A B 500. Isn't it what you need ?

Comment: On my last comment above I have a zip file with 2 tables. The sample is what I have and the result is what I want. When I implemented what you have suggested, I don't get the result I want.

Comment: could you please add a print screen of the first lines of your 2 tables by editing your question ?